# TFileStream is slower than TMemoryStream

Tags: delphi, file-read

This is my second question on SO, I hope I'll format it correctly.

I found out at work that TFileStream is slower than TMemoryStream and I have really no idea as to why that could be the case. Hence I decided to do some testing.

In the application in which I found out this behaviour I loaded all files in a folder, and for each file I had to read it byte by byte. After switching from `TFileStream` to `TMemoryStream` the execution became istantaneous. To test this I made the functions below, in which the same file (`FileName`) is loaded into a `TStream` `Nr` times, each time the stream is read until its end `Siz` bytes at a time (I'm really sorry for my English).

The functions I used to test it are:

The first is a test for `TFileStream`, because it doesn't have a method `LoadFromFile` I have to create and destroy it each time.

```
function TestFileStream(Nr, Siz: Integer): Double;
var
  sw: TStopWatch;
  Stream: TFileStream;
  I: Integer;
  buffer: TBytes;
begin
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  System.SetLength(buffer, Siz);
  for I := 0 to Nr - 1 do
    begin
      Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
      try
        Stream.Position := 0;
        while Stream.Position + Siz < Stream.Size do
          Stream.ReadBuffer(buffer, Siz);
      finally
        Stream.Free;
      end;
    end;
  Result := sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
  sw.Stop;
end;
```

The second is a test for `TMemoryStream`, also this time the `TMemoryStream` is created and destroyed `Nr` times.

```
function TestMemoryStream(Nr, Siz: Integer): Double;
var
  sw: TStopWatch;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  I: Integer;
  buffer: TBytes;
begin
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  System.SetLength(buffer, Siz);
  for I := 0 to Nr - 1 do
    begin
      Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        Stream.LoadFromFile(FileName);
        Stream.Position := 0;
        while Stream.Position + Siz < Stream.Size do
          Stream.ReadBuffer(buffer, Siz);
      finally
        Stream.Free;
      end;
    end;
  Result := sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
  sw.Stop;
end;
```

The third is a test for `TMemoryStream`, this time the `TMemoryStream` is created once.

```
function TestKeepMemoryStream(Nr, Siz: Integer): Double;
var
  sw: TStopWatch;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  I: Integer;
  buffer: TBytes;
begin
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  System.SetLength(buffer, Siz);
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    for I := 0 to Nr - 1 do
      begin
        Stream.LoadFromFile(FileName);
        Stream.Position := 0;
        while Stream.Position + Siz < Stream.Size do
          Stream.ReadBuffer(buffer, Siz);
      end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
  Result := sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
  sw.Stop;
end;
```

The results are the following:

```
Nr = 100, Siz = 1
TFileStream:        27,8980448s
TMemoryStream:      0,1571709s
TMemoryStream Kept: 0,1607682s


Nr = 100, Siz = 16
TFileStream:        1,7674029s
TMemoryStream:      0,044709s
TMemoryStream Kept: 0,0432958s


Nr = 100, Siz = 4096
TFileStream:        0,0427971s
TMemoryStream:      0,0325959s
TMemoryStream Kept: 0,0316288s
```

What strikes me as odd is that `TMemoryStream` uses a `TFileStream` to load a file and the `ReadBuffer` method is inherited from `TStream`, so there shouldn't be a difference, as far as my uderstanding goes. Do you have an idea which could explain this?

Comment: "*I have really no idea as to why [TFileStream is slower than TMemoryStream].*" - because disk I/O is usually slower than memory I/O in general.

Comment: You could look at TBufferedFileStream. https://delphiaball.co.uk/2016/04/29/faster-filestream-tbufferedfilestream/

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I understand it now. I should have looked with more attention into how `ReadBuffer` and consequentely `Read` were implemented for each of the class

Comment: @BruceMcGee Thank you, I'll try it next time I have some free time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your `Siz` parameter is small, `TFileStream` will access the disk each time to read a very small chunk of data, whereas in your code `TMemoryStream` accesses the disk once, and then the small chunks are read from memory. If you make the `Siz` variable the size of the file on disk, you should not see a difference.

Comment: You are incredibly right, thank you.
I should have looked at the code of `ReadBuffer` more carefully, lesson learned for the next time.

Comment: Depends on the media: "disk" can also be a fast access storage, such as SSD; or the OS could have cached the file already. In those cases, differences should be difficult to notice. It also demonstrates the disadvantages of accessing a file many times over accessing it only few times.

Comment: @AmigoJack Even on a fast SSD reading a file byte by byte will be terribly slow. Why? Because your computer will spend more time handling I/O requests than reading the data.

Comment: @NihmarIsProgramming There is nothing to do with the code in `ReadBuffer `. It is the virtual method `Read` that matters. Your understanding of Delphi's class inheritance is not accurate: The `ReadBuffer` method is inherited from `TStream`, but it can be virtual/dynamic or it can call virtual/dynamic methods. So the implementation can be significantly different.

Comment: @W.Chang I was imprecise in the previous comment, I meant that I should have followed the functions called by `ReadBuffer` and how they differed, the first of them being `Read`. Still, yes, I should improve my understanding of Delphi